# speed up multiple awaited calls in nodejs

Tags: node.js, promise

I have 10 functions similar to the following (database queries):

```
    async loadEmails(){
       this.emails = await (EmailEntity as any).findAll(this.where)
    }



    async loadUrls(){
       this.urls = await (UrlEntity as any).findAll(this.where)
    }
```

I am calling them all one after one (10).

I want to speed up the execution.

```
for(const i in toLoad){
   let name = toLoad[i];
   name = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
   const exec = 'this.load' + name + '()';
   await eval(exec)
}
```

what is the best way to parralelize `await eval(exec)`?
Promise.all? if so, how?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use await in the foor loop because it will wait until the 1. Promise is resolved before starting the 2. call. Instead call each method, **but don't await yet** and then after you started all your async calls(after the loop) await them all at once with `Promise.all([Promise1, Promise2])`.

```
let promises = [];

for(const i in toLoad){
   let name = toLoad[i];
   name = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
   const exec = 'this.load' + name + '()';
   promise.push(eval(exec)); // store the promise
}
await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: Thanks. But isnt promise.push(eval(exec)) execute the eval bfore?

Comment: yes it will execute all eval(exec) in 'parallel' and then await them after the loop. Mean it's possible that eval3 finishes before eval2.